# Camera view aspect ratio doesn't match output proportions?

Tags: camera, output

When in camera view, if I change 'Resolution X' in the Output properties tab, I expect the width of the viewfinder in the camera view to change.  However, it is the height of the camera view that changes. What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The camera view has a fixed maximum area of 1:1 proportions corresponding to the "sensor" of your camera, then an appropriate rectangle is drawn inside that square area to represent the ratio defined by your output values:

[image]

This is because, by default, your *[Sensor Fit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html#camera)* is set to *Auto*. You can choose to set one axis to be the decisive side from *Properties > Object Data (Camera) > Sensor Fit*. *Horizontal* will fix the *X* axis, so the output frame can go outside the sensor area on the vertical, and vice versa.

You can enable the sensor outline (white dashed line in the screenshot) from *Viewport Display* in the same properties panel:

[image]

Comment: More contrived than expected, but thanks for sorting me out!