# Scaling and centering generated objects to take up entire camera viewing width resolution using geometry nodes

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes, eevee-render-engine, mathematics

Scaling and centering generated objects to take up entire camera viewing width resolution using **geometry nodes**.

I have an output resolution set to **7000px (x)** and **3900px (y)**.  I would like to **center** and **scale** my object to **fill the camera viewing width when it's rendered**.

**Example Setup:**

[image: img1]

**So it would fill up the width like this when rendered:**

[image: img2]

**My Logic:**

1. Use the Attribute Statistics node to get the dimensions of object.
2. Calculate the dimensions needed to be centered and scaled to fit within camera view port when rendering (**I'm missing this part.** (Output resolution set to **7000px (x)** and **3900px (y)**)
3. Use a scale or transform node to make sure it fits within the camera view when rendering.

The reason for this is I'm testing a way to generate multiple objects that have different sizes and **some of those objects won't fit within the camera output view resolution**, so **I would like to scale and center the object to make sure it fits within the camera view when it's batch rendered**.

**See Blend file below:**

[image]

Comment: I don't think this would be possible with a perspective camera—even when you keep the focal length the same for ex, shapes of the objects will make a big difference for their visual boundaries: https://i.imgur.com/gN3wuwB.mp4 Is it enough that they're always *contained* within the frame, or do you need them to *exactly fit* inside (touching the frame)? Exact fit would be relatively easy with an orthographic camera.

Comment: @Kuboå Yes the orthographic camera would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, at least in an easy way, with a perspective camera as there are too many things that go into it: camera's focal length, its position in 3D space, the less than immediately obvious [relationship between Blender's camera sensor and the output resolution ratio](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282097/71578)... Even when you keep many of these settings the same for a certain setup and fit the objects into the same bounding box, shapes of the objects (their depth in perspective) will make a big difference for their visual boundaries:

[image]

However, things get much easier when you're OK with an orthographic camera. We can create a "container box" with dimensions that match the ratio of the output resolution, then scale our objects so they fit exactly inside that box:

[image]

In the setup above, I'm doing that by first checking if an object's front face ratio ($X\over Z$ dimensions of its `Bounding Box`) is smaller than our output resolution ratio (${7000\over3900} :1.7948$) to determine whether it is a vertical or horizontal object. If it is vertical, we scale it so the *Z* height of its bounding box is the same as the *Container Box*; if it is horizontal, we do that for its *X* length.

I expose the *Container Bo*x dimensions in the modifier window so I can copy the output resolution numbers as a driver to control them (purple color indicating that they are being controlled by a driver). If I set the orthographic camera's *Sensor Fit* to *Horizontal*, I can use the driver from output *Resolution X* to control its *Orthographic Scale* as well, so when I change the output resolution, the container box and the camera frame will automatically fit perfectly flush with each other:

[image]

[image]