# Ambient occlusion not working in shading viewport / render

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes, hdri, ambient-occlusion

Ambient occlusion not working in shading viewport / render.

I'm trying to render whats in **GN_CONTAINER BOX** with **Ambient occlusion using the forest built in HDRI** but it's not working.  I believe I enabled all the options but I seem to be missing something.

[image: img]

See what I enabled below:

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image: img]

[image: img4]

[image: img5]

For back history: [Scaling and centering generated objects to take up entire camera viewing width resolution using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283795/scaling-and-centering-generated-objects-to-take-up-entire-camera-viewing-width-r)

Blend file below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a *Scene > Unit Scale* of $0.001$ so the default values are way off—1000 times smaller than usual. For Eevee, set the *Ambient Occlusion > Distance* value in *Render Properties* to $0.2$ or something higher and you should see the occlusion:

[image]<sub>*Be aware that in your setup the "Render Pass" mode in the shading options dropdown is set to "Ambient Occlusion"*</sub>

Cycles doesn't have that option of course, and doesn't seem to respond well to this difference in scale. If you switch to the standard *Combined* render pass mode, you might notice it does have a little bit of AO, but very weak. That's due to the `Ambient Occlusion` node's default *Distance* value of $1.0$ in the shader. Multiply that with a bigger value as well and occlusion will pop up:

[image]